# use javascript to display label when checkbox is checked in an asp.net repeater

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have an asp.net repeater that has 4 columns populated by a dataset that is pulled from a sql server. In one of the fields is a checkbox and all the others are labels. one field is called "type". Each record will be one of two types. What I would like to do is use javascript to check if a check box is checked and if so display the count for the "type" in a textbox. for example there would be two textboxes one would display "type 1 has 3 checked" and the other would display "type 2 has 3 checked". I currently have a Javascript function (see below) that counts all the checkboxes that are checked and displays a count in a text box, but I would like to be able to keep track of the count for each type. Is there any way in javascript I can capture the type when it is checking if the checkbox is checked.

JavaScript

```
function checkrpt() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var count = 0

    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {

        if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox") {
            if (inputs[i].checked == true)

                    count += 1;
            }
            if (count > 6) {
                inputs[i].checked = false;
            }
        }

    if (count > 0) {
        document.getElementById('txtSelectionStatus').value = count + ' items have been selected';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('txtSelectionStatus').value = 'No items have been selected';
    }
    if (count > 6) {
        document.getElementById('txtSelectionStatus').value = 'You can only select 6 itmes';
    }
}
```

ASP:Repeater

```
 <asp:repeater id="rptStep1Data" runat="server">
   <HeaderTemplate>
     <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr style="backgound-color:#DDDDDD;">
         <td width="150px" align="center" class="tableheader"><b>Add To Grid</b></td>
         <td width="100px" class="tableheader" align="center"><b>Distance</b></td>
         <td width="400px" align="left" class="tableheader"><b>Address</b></td>
         <td width="100px" align="center" class="tableheader"><b>Type</b></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
           <div style="overflow:scroll; overflow-x:hidden; height: 300px; width: 100%">
             <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   </HeaderTemplate>
   <ITEMTEMPLATE>
               <tr>
                 <td  width="148px" align="center" class="content">
                   <asp:checkbox id="chkSelected" runat="server" onClick="javascript:checkrpt()" Checked='<%# makeChecked(Container.DataItem("Selected")) %>' />
                 </td>
                 <td width="100px" align="center" class="content">
                   <asp:label id="lblDistance" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("Distance") %>' />                                                    
                 </td>
                 <td width="390px" align="left" style="padding-left:10px" class="content">                                                    
                   <asp:label id="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("Address") %>' />                                                    
                 </td>
                 <td width="100px" align="center" class="content">                                                    
                   <asp:label id="lblType" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("Type") %>' />                                                    
                 </td>
               </tr>
   </ITEMTEMPLATE>
   <ALTERNATINGITEMTEMPLATE>
               <tr>
                 <td align="center" class="content">
                   <asp:checkbox id="chkSelected" runat="server" onClick="javascript:checkrpt()" Checked='<%# makeChecked(Container.DataItem("Selected")) %>' />
                 </td>
                 <td align="center" class="content">                                                    
                   <asp:label id="lblDistance" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("Distance") %>' />                                                    
                 </td>
                 <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px" class="content">                                                    
                   <asp:label id="lblAddress" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("Address") %>' />                                                    
                 </td>
                 <td align="center" class="content">                                                    
                   <asp:label id="lblGLA" runat="server" Text='<%# Container.DataItem("Type") %>' />                                                    
                 </td>
               </tr>
   </ALTERNATINGITEMTEMPLATE>
   <FooterTemplate>
             </table>
           </div>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
   </FooterTemplate>
 </asp:repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onClientClick= "checkrpt()"` instead of `onClick` event of `checkbox`.
`onClientClick` runs client side javascript code.